# 'If null' operator to return an empty String

Tags: flutter, dart

I am doing a null check with the operator '??'.

```
Text(contact.rating.toString() ?? " ",
```

However the text shows `null` when it is null, instead of

What's the best way to write this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `contact.rating` is null, so you have to do the following

`Text(contact.rating?.toString() ?? " "),`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

`Text(contact.rating != null ? contact.rating.toString() : " ")`